# C++ derivative class with virtual function

Tags: c++, derived-class, virtual-functions

I have a problem with some task. I need to write an derived class in which I need to be sure, that vector FVect cointains only characters <'a'; 'z'>.

```
class Something {
private:
   char FVect[3];

protected:
   virtual void setValue(int _idx, char _val) { FVect[_idx] = _val; }

public:
   Something() {};
};
```

I don't know exactly how to write a method in derived class (without making changes in class Something) since FVect is private.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Use `setValue` in the derived class?

Comment: Are you asking how to derive another class from `class Something` or are you asking how to ensure that `FVect` only contains characters from 'a' to 'z'? Your question is too un clear and too broad. Please elaborate and [edit].

Comment: The term is *derived* class, not derivative.

Comment: Thanks for answers. My task sounds exactly like this: "Write a definition of a class derived to 'Something' in which we are sure, that every element of vector FVect contains only <'a'; 'z'> character"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current setup, the only thing you can do is implement `setValue()` in the class derived from `Something` and raise an exception if `_val` is outside the valid values, otherwise calling the base class method if it is valid:

```
class Derived : public Something {
    ...
    void setValue(int _idx, char _val) {
        if ((_val < 'a') || (_val > 'z')) throw std::invalid_argument( "invalid character" );
        Something::setValue(_idx, _val);
    }
    ...
};
```